# Passing parameters in logon script in GPO failed

Tags: windows, vbscript, parameters, gpo

As you see in my GPO settings

[image: My GPO settings]

I have a VBScript and call it as a logon script via GPO in domain controller. The script is running at a logon but the parameters are not passed. Any ideas why not?

On [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908.aspx) they say

> In Script Parameters, type the parameters you want to use as you would type them on the command line. For example, if your script included parameters called //logo (display banner) and //I (interactive mode), type: //logo //I.

So it should be possible the way I do it, right?

Because AnsgarWiechers asked:
I check if the script is running by

```
Set objFsoLog=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outFileLog="C:\ScriptLog.txt"
Set objFileLog = objFsoLog.CreateTextFile(outFileLog,True)
objFileLog.Write "script wurde wenigstens ausgeführt" & vbCrLf
objFileLog.Close
```

at the beginning od the script.
And I check the parameters by this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
MsgBox WScript.Arguments(0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Description
End If
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
MsgBox WScript.Arguments(1)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox Err.Description
End If
```

gpresult /h gives the following output for my GPO:
[image: screenshot]
But the script is saved in the logon scripts:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, the policy should work. How did you verify that the script is actually running at logon and that the parameters are not passed to it? Did you check if the policy is being applied to the user in question?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I made a textfile output at the beginning of the script. This .txt gets made. And I made a MsgBox with WScript.Arguments(0). This gives an "out of range" error.

Comment: Is the correct policy applied? Check with `gpresult /h` or `rsop.msc`. Also, the code checking the parameters would produce the same error for either missing parameter. How did you verify that the first one is missing rather than the second one?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers My system is in german but I try to find the right english words: The GPO is denied. The path is right but the reason for denieing is empty. What could be the reason ?

Comment: The message means that the *User Configuration* branch of your GPO is empty. Double check if that particular GPO actually has a logon script defined under *User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts*.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers But the script is saved under this path ....

Comment: Try using "cscript" as the script name (since that's the executable that runs .vbs files) and put the .vbs file as the first parameter (with quotes if it contains any spaces).

Comment: @HarryJohnston can you explain this a little bit more ? where should i write my parameters  if i do it like this ?

Comment: The parameter string would be: `\\server\path\script.vbs testgroup testdomain`

Comment: @HarryJohnston If I do it like this it is not even running at all

Comment: Skriptname has to be the filepath with the script at the end and parameter has to be "testgroup testdomain"